# What are the hubs for non-WiFi, DIY/open/hackable devices?

Tags: mqtt, sensors, system-architecture

I would like to future-proof my home automation architecture

**Today**, I have a very decentralized setup:

- an MQTT broker (Mosquitto)
- WiFi switches: two on-the-wire ones (Sonoff Basic) and one wall switch (Sonoff Touch), all of them connected to the MQTT broker
- Node-RED as the glue to automate their interactions

I have also installed Home Assistant and Domoticz but I am not sure yet about their use, maybe as a rarely used frontend? Anyway, they are both connected to the MQTT broker as well.

This is a decentralized setup where each of the components talk to the MQTT bus. It also avoids "vendor" lock-in: the automation mechanism is on Node-RED but could also be based on the capacities of Home Assistant or Domoticz, or others.

**Tomorrow**, I would ideally keep all devices standalone, Wifi enabled and directly connected to the MQTT. This is probably not going to happen:

- I will have some sensors which will communicate via BLE or a 433 MHz signal, to some hub, which need to pass the information further
- Some devices may not be MQTT-compatible

The sensors I have in mind are of the DIY/hackable kind, without a proprietary protocol on top.

**What are the hubs for such devices?**

Specifically I am wondering wether they rely on complete solutions such as Domoticz/HA vs. something simple implemented on a RPi or ideally an Arduino, which would just bridge the wireless transmission with MQTT (getting the basic message from the sensor and sending it to the MQTT hub for further processing by something else).

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is unanswerably broad.  Given that there are limitless things which can fall within your "these devices" there will be limitless specific hub needs.  Even where the frequency and modulation method of radio communication might be comparable, potentially even when lower protocol layers like zigbee or BLE are shared, it's still far more likely than not that the higher protocol and message needs will be unique.  Typically that means a vendor-specific hub, but there are a few starts of open source solutions which might span brands to some degree.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thanks, I see that my question was not precise enough. I had DIY kind of devices in mind and was wondering about their reliance on complete solutions such as Domoticz/HA vs something simple implemented on a RPi or an Arduino for instance, which would just bridge the wireless transmission with MQTT (getting the basic message from the sensor and sending it to the MQTT hub for further processing by something else). I will update my question.

Comment: I'd recommend you look at hanging the local radio off of a modifiable embedded linux router platform capable of running some custom software to do translation.  Either something sold as being able to be your primary wifi router, or a low end one sold for IoT purposes, for example the MT7688 or the AR9331. For simpler tasks where you don't need a full-service operating system you could consider an ESP8266 or ESP32.